# Using the each function to pass results to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I guess this might be a noob question but when using the each iterator, is it possible to send the results to a predefined function? I have only seen examples where the function is defined in the parantheses. Here is what I would like to do:

```
function setCheckboxes(key, value) {
    ....some code....
}

context.find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(setCheckboxes(key, value));
```

Is this possible? Or do I have to implement it this way:

```
context.find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(key, value) {
    ....some code....
});
```

Comment: You are probably using jQuery. If so, please retag our question to include it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just give the function reference as the callback for `each`.

```
context.find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(setCheckboxes);
```

In your callback `setCheckboxes` key will be the index and value will be the element (DOM element).

This is no different from writing an anonymous function, where you get the same 2 arguments, in this case you are just giving a reference to a function that expects the same 2 arguments. So the context inside the callback i.e `setCheckboxes` will be the DOM element.

Comment: Yeah just be wise that you can also use `this` inside of `setCheckboxes` to access the current element.

Comment: @JamundFerguson True.. Infact i mentioned it indirectly saying this is no different from an anonymous func.. I will that explicitly in my answer as well..

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
function setCheckboxes(key, value) {
    ....some code....
}

context.find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(key, value){
    setCheckboxes(key, value);
});
```

Comment: `key` and `value` are `undefined` in your current example